# Perform a FFT of a signal in Objective-C and compare results with MATLAB

Tags: ios, xcode, matlab, fft, vdsp

I'm trying to perform the FFT of a signal in Objective-C.
The signal is composed of 180 samples. The signal is the following:

```
float testFFT [180] = { 0.0000000000, 0.0000432091, 0.0001739833, 0.0003786624, 0.0006653523, 0.0010579729, 0.0015538626, 0.0022084275, 0.0029233105, 0.0037457265, 0.0048239902, 0.0061722184, 0.0074678478, 0.0019116795, -0.0216427371, -0.0583566576, -0.0879606530, -0.0966484919, -0.0844414756, -0.0587274097, -0.0275895316, 0.0020122994, 0.0238022581, 0.0301328432, 0.0223602522, 0.0108049158, 0.0026056657, 0.0015842463, 0.0078394171, 0.0178532675, 0.0289764665, 0.0387034491, 0.0457277447, 0.0503653251, 0.0511394553, 0.0495931208, 0.0491546877, 0.0486858748, 0.0486131087, 0.0533984452, 0.0587649047, 0.0659925416, 0.0777209774, 0.0856716558, 0.0555341654, -0.1010383219, -0.3626580238, -0.5730977058, -0.6356759071, -0.5587731600, -0.4057232738, -0.2299835384, -0.0666809455, 0.0577908531, 0.1170516908, 0.1059532985, 0.0634752810, 0.0284998771, 0.0149525786, 0.0262031760, 0.0470281616, 0.0667090788, 0.0911477804, 0.1096955463, 0.1211226359, 0.1271539181, 0.1249239892, 0.1236920506, 0.1237676740, 0.1250490546, 0.1243178397, 0.1247144639, 0.1260439157, 0.1231973395, 0.1264088154, 0.1277698576, -0.0030977963, -0.3769126236, -0.8328822851, -1.1014552116, -1.0855975151, -0.8706340790, -0.5911422372, -0.3257140219, -0.0960753635, 0.0647964701, 0.1323186159, 0.1257916987, 0.0897259787, 0.0630174652, 0.0530946776, 0.0599082038, 0.0814570710, 0.1065363511, 0.1312004477, 0.1502322406, 0.1570600569, 0.1507443786, 0.1410262287, 0.1309887618, 0.1199141294, 0.1154099405, 0.1160193905, 0.1228033155, 0.1373534203, 0.1516684294, 0.1679655612, 0.1372354180, -0.1066413969, -0.5384752750, -0.8941160440, -0.9979212284, -0.8646196723, -0.6145014763, -0.3477802575, -0.1164548695, 0.0449491963, 0.1089080572, 0.0893236622, 0.0330192894, -0.0108435927, -0.0175555795, 0.0047061597, 0.0339520164, 0.0558914244, 0.0686639696, 0.0742127448, 0.0779310316, 0.0802902952, 0.0771160051, 0.0714451671, 0.0660981461, 0.0637993589, 0.0645155609, 0.0667568296, 0.0722958520, 0.0757482499, 0.0236506276, -0.1267153770, -0.3023732007, -0.3952195346, -0.3767756522, -0.2849329114, -0.1723687500, -0.0716818050, 0.0028261179, 0.0375415571, 0.0343864709, 0.0144051891, -0.0021018211, -0.0056255818, 0.0027398649, 0.0138968918, 0.0204720702, 0.0226374995, 0.0215674732, 0.0184285343, 0.0154026123, 0.0144131510, 0.0145750465, 0.0143866902, 0.0138069429, 0.0127558541, 0.0114914598, 0.0105097489, 0.0059011118, -0.0082570817, -0.0260418169, -0.0354200974, -0.0332562923, -0.0243141986, -0.0146232471, -0.0073889960, -0.0028967261, -0.0005872814, 0.0001664309, 0.0001607906, 0.0000362319, 0.0000018391, 0.0000000001};
```

In my project I've imported the Accelerate Framework and the code I used to perform the FFT is the following :

```
// -- Number of Sample
int numSamples = 256; // i use 256 because if i use 128 i don't considered 52 values

// -- Init FFT
// - Setup the length
vDSP_Length log2n = log2f(numSamples);

FFTSetup fftSetup = vDSP_create_fftsetup(log2n, FFT_RADIX2);

int nOver2 = numSamples/2;

// - Define complex buffer
COMPLEX_SPLIT A;
A.realp = (float *) malloc(nOver2*sizeof(float));
A.imagp = (float *) malloc(nOver2*sizeof(float));

// - Pack samples:
vDSP_ctoz((COMPLEX*)testFFT, 2, &A, 1, numSamples/2);


// -- Run FFT
vDSP_fft_zrip(fftSetup, &A, 1, log2n, FFT_FORWARD);

// -- Convert COMPLEX_SPLIT A result to magnitudes
float amp[256];
amp[0] = A.realp[0]/(numSamples*2);

for(int i=1; i<numSamples; i++) {
    amp[i]=sqrt(A.realp[i]*A.realp[i]+A.imagp[i]*A.imagp[i]);
}
```

Then my output magnitude vector is :

```
gainFFTTest = [ -0.022274, 8.984702, 4.144551, 0.809363, 0.941445, 2.347171, 7.364040, 16.668034, 23.730299, 21.198763, 11.301848, 3.042607, 1.467086, 2.339780, 4.816690, 10.835640, 17.146097, 17.648199, 11.441965, 4.918188, 2.744555, 2.347548, 3.812189, 7.538163, 12.398130, 14.082799, 10.534361, 5.591731, 3.525628, 2.503175, 2.460673, 3.326554, 5.311335, 6.440503, 5.227306, 2.916733, 1.815048, 1.607442, 1.587724, 1.587670, 2.045040, 2.519320, 2.300229, 1.566618, 0.928839, 0.690373, 0.905959, 1.130702, 1.337159, 1.626698, 1.553285, 1.114764, 0.753150, 0.591139, 0.653807, 0.852154, 0.836321, 0.835025, 0.851975, 0.664267, 0.443333, 0.324886, 0.312793, 0.420463, 0.429140, 0.355254, 0.340838, 0.290471, 0.214697, 0.174454, 0.153486, 0.190136, 0.208401, 0.164705, 0.138394, 0.115397, 0.075669, 0.065181, 0.077329, 0.110584, 0.143098, 0.131150, 0.086918, 0.063639, 0.051252, 0.064340, 0.077155, 0.072525, 0.080241, 0.088438, 0.070221, 0.051208, 0.040207, 0.028501, 0.025500, 0.029908, 0.042129, 0.045339, 0.033957, 0.019551, 0.015710, 0.025570, 0.028711, 0.017500, 0.006169, 0.013390, 0.013368, 0.007762, 0.005007, 0.008410, 0.010856, 0.009631, 0.012508, 0.018056, 0.019384, 0.014050, 0.006475, 0.005373, 0.006383, 0.006624, 0.006779, 0.006790, 0.005996, 0.004189, 0.002242, 0.001977, 0.002130, 0.001396, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000];
```

Often i obtained NAN i INF values why ???
Then  I put this in MATLAB (to check the result ) and perform : 
   plot(gainFFTTest)

and, after I zoomed in as much, I see this plot :

[image]

After this i Put the testFFT array in MATLAB  with this command:

```
testFFT = [ 0.0000000000, 0.0000432091, 0.0001739833, 0.0003786624, 0.0006653523, 0.0010579729, 0.0015538626, 0.0022084275, 0.0029233105, 0.0037457265, 0.0048239902, 0.0061722184, 0.0074678478, 0.0019116795, -0.0216427371, -0.0583566576, -0.0879606530, -0.0966484919, -0.0844414756, -0.0587274097, -0.0275895316, 0.0020122994, 0.0238022581, 0.0301328432, 0.0223602522, 0.0108049158, 0.0026056657, 0.0015842463, 0.0078394171, 0.0178532675, 0.0289764665, 0.0387034491, 0.0457277447, 0.0503653251, 0.0511394553, 0.0495931208, 0.0491546877, 0.0486858748, 0.0486131087, 0.0533984452, 0.0587649047, 0.0659925416, 0.0777209774, 0.0856716558, 0.0555341654, -0.1010383219, -0.3626580238, -0.5730977058, -0.6356759071, -0.5587731600, -0.4057232738, -0.2299835384, -0.0666809455, 0.0577908531, 0.1170516908, 0.1059532985, 0.0634752810, 0.0284998771, 0.0149525786, 0.0262031760, 0.0470281616, 0.0667090788, 0.0911477804, 0.1096955463, 0.1211226359, 0.1271539181, 0.1249239892, 0.1236920506, 0.1237676740, 0.1250490546, 0.1243178397, 0.1247144639, 0.1260439157, 0.1231973395, 0.1264088154, 0.1277698576, -0.0030977963, -0.3769126236, -0.8328822851, -1.1014552116, -1.0855975151, -0.8706340790, -0.5911422372, -0.3257140219, -0.0960753635, 0.0647964701, 0.1323186159, 0.1257916987, 0.0897259787, 0.0630174652, 0.0530946776, 0.0599082038, 0.0814570710, 0.1065363511, 0.1312004477, 0.1502322406, 0.1570600569, 0.1507443786, 0.1410262287, 0.1309887618, 0.1199141294, 0.1154099405, 0.1160193905, 0.1228033155, 0.1373534203, 0.1516684294, 0.1679655612, 0.1372354180, -0.1066413969, -0.5384752750, -0.8941160440, -0.9979212284, -0.8646196723, -0.6145014763, -0.3477802575, -0.1164548695, 0.0449491963, 0.1089080572, 0.0893236622, 0.0330192894, -0.0108435927, -0.0175555795, 0.0047061597, 0.0339520164, 0.0558914244, 0.0686639696, 0.0742127448, 0.0779310316, 0.0802902952, 0.0771160051, 0.0714451671, 0.0660981461, 0.0637993589, 0.0645155609, 0.0667568296, 0.0722958520, 0.0757482499, 0.0236506276, -0.1267153770, -0.3023732007, -0.3952195346, -0.3767756522, -0.2849329114, -0.1723687500, -0.0716818050, 0.0028261179, 0.0375415571, 0.0343864709, 0.0144051891, -0.0021018211, -0.0056255818, 0.0027398649, 0.0138968918, 0.0204720702, 0.0226374995, 0.0215674732, 0.0184285343, 0.0154026123, 0.0144131510, 0.0145750465, 0.0143866902, 0.0138069429, 0.0127558541, 0.0114914598, 0.0105097489, 0.0059011118, -0.0082570817, -0.0260418169, -0.0354200974, -0.0332562923, -0.0243141986, -0.0146232471, -0.0073889960, -0.0028967261, -0.0005872814, 0.0001664309, 0.0001607906, 0.0000362319, 0.0000018391, 0.0000000001];
```

Then i perform the FFT and plot the gain :

```
gain = abs(fft(testFFT));
plot(gain)
```

And the plot now is correct :

[image]

- > Where am I wrong ?? how can I get the same results in Objective-C?

Please help me.

Comment: It looks like you've used `abs` in MATLAB, but not in Objective-C. Was this intentional?

Comment: I perform the abs in Objective-C by doing sqrt(rePart^2 + imPart^2)

Comment: FFT of real data is symmetric. Could objective-C FFT be computing only half the values? The shape of FFT seems same if you consider only half the spectrum. Scale factor could be different depending on what kind of scaling the FFT algorithm used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Resolved this issue by putting the NAN and INF value at zero and by using 256 samples instead 180.

Answer (score 0):

Your Objective-C code does not match the Matlab code:

1. There is no windowing in the matlab code. In addition, the test data you provided seems to be already multiplied by a window function.
2. You seem to use an Radix2 implementation in the Objective-C code. Matlab does not use Radix2 if the length of the signal does not match a power of 2. Refer to http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html , section "algorithm" for details.

Your Objective-C code seems strange. Radix2 is not defined for non power of 2 signals. The number of samples supplied (180) does not match numSamples. What are the implications of this? Does the algorithm fill the remaining part of the signal with zeros (zero-padding), or will it just read the memory following your array?

Comment: You're right, the test data is the result of a band-pass filtering and then multiplied with an Hann window. The result of this process is the array "fftTest" of 180 samples.

If I do the zero-padding for the rest of 76 samples the result doesn't change.


My aim is to obtain the same result of Matlab. How i perform this in Objective-C?

PS: I'm going to edit the question and delete che part of the "window"